# protected references in Java

Tags: java, protected

I have three classes:

```
package pac;

public class A {
    protected A a;  
    protected final int i = 10;
}

public class B extends A {

    void foo() {
        A a = new A();
        int b = a.a.i;  //compiles fine
    }
}

package another.pac;

public class C extends A {

    void foo() {
        A a = new A();
        int b = a.a.i;  //Does not compile. a.a is inaccessible
    }
}
```

Why can't we access a protected member from a put into another package, but from the same package we can? They both are subclasses of one, therefore acces should have been permitted.

[JLS 6.6.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.1) says:

> If the access is by a field access expression E.Id, or a method
>   invocation expression E.Id(...), or a method reference expression E ::
>   Id, where E is a Primary expression (§15.8), then the access is
>   permitted if and only if the type of E is S or a subclass of S.

The class `C` satisifies the requerement. What's wrong?

Comment: That's the idea of protected, that only classes in the same package can access it... Otherwise make it public

Comment: @Danielson *That's the idea of protected, that only classes in the same package can access it... Otherwise make it public*. Not true.

Comment: @ChetanKinger good explanation... The non-packaged class cannot directly access the field... It can through inheritance, but then you are calling a class inside the package

Comment: @Danielson *but then you are calling a class inside the package*. Not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `protected` member can be accessed in a subclass outside the package only through inheritance. Try this instead :

```
public class C extends A {

    void foo() {
       int b = i;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I just don't see how it answers my question. I believe that you just didn't understand what I was looking for. I've made it clear now.

Comment: @stella You just made an edit quoting the JLS which was not a part of your quesiton when I posted the answer. My answer did answer your question before you edited it. Even after your edit, my answer still explains the golden rule for `protected` members.  What part of *A protected member can be accessed in a subclass outside the package only through inheritance* did you not understand? Don't downvote answers because of a lack of understanding on your part.

Comment: No, now I got the rules. It's clear.

Answer (score 2):

There are no needs to make a reference every time. I think you didn't understand [*Inheritence..*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

```
public class B extends A {

    void foo() {
       // A a = new A(); No need to instantiate it here as B extends A
        int b = i;  //No nedd to refer it through a.a.i  
    }
}

package another.pac;

public class C extends A {

    void foo() {
        C c=new C();
        int d=c.i//this will work fine
       //   A a = new A(); same as above explanation
        int b = i;  //same as above and even a.i will not compile
    }
}
```

Now Your protected variable will be accessible here..

Answer (score 1):

Class A is apart of package pac;

and Class C is apart of package another.pac therefore it will be unable to access its member. If C is apart of package pac then it would be able to access the member

See the following post: [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)